# Better way to handle OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in SonarQube Compute Engine

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I'm having a huge maven project on which the SonarQube analysis is been done, from maven everything is fine but the SonarQube background task fails because of OutOfMemoryError exception.

I have increased the heap memory for compute engine and its working for now, but is there a way to handle this in SonarQube without increasing the memory, like split the background task in to smaller tasks and combine the results?

Comment: Only if you split the code-base into a collection of independent projects and build them independently.

Comment: @StephenC yes, that’s what I planning to do but it will create multiple projects in sonarqube, so if I need combined metrics have to do manually

Comment: What do you mean by `huge maven project`?  And how many memory have you configured?

Comment: @khmarbaise i had 512MB, now changed to 1 GB. My question is, is there a better way to handle it in SonarQube? What i meant by huge maven project is the number of source code files and lines of code is huge enough to through OutOfMemory exception.

Comment: Ok..That sounds like a small project. I have currently one with 1.7 million lines of code and 850 modules in a single build. The configuration to get the SonarQube analysis is currently with 4 GiB...The question is: What is the real problem with that?

Comment: @khmarbaise my machine only has 2GB RAM I cannot keep on increasing the heap memory. I understand the heap memory limit is based on physical memory. OutOfMemory is happening because the analysis is done in one go. My question is is there a way to spit the analysis (Background Task) in to smaller tasks or some thing similar

Comment: Only as already suggest to split the project...and to be honest that sounds you are running on very limited resources. You should get larger machines...cause that will block you always...and using a larger machine will make your life easier and faster...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Compute Engine needs to load all data included in the report sent by the scanner in memory to be able to process it.

You can see in the log of the scanner the size of the report, to get a rough idea of how much data there is to process. It will of course be related to how many lines of source code is being analyzed.

```
[INFO] Analysis report generated in 3282ms, dir size=53 MB
[INFO] Analysis reports compressed in 5909ms, zip size=28 MB
[INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 3252ms
```

There is currently no way to have the scanner send fragments of the report. You can analyze for example different modules of the project separately, but this will result in different projects being created in SonarQube.

Increasing the heap size is a good solution, and using 1GB seems perfectly reasonable.